# Why do we use char* as a buffer, why not a string in boost::asio?

Tags: c++, buffer, boost-asio

Recently I have been reading a book about network programming with boost::asio, and from what I have understood, buffer is like any other memory space in address space of the program and we assign that to the socket so that we can do I/O operations.

The first thing I don't understand is, why do we need a separate thing called "buffer"? Why not just write the content in a string, and then when we receive put it in the string?

The second thing I don't understand is, why is `char*` or `char[]` used as a buffer, why not `int[]`, which can store ASCII values of everything that comes through? It's just a memory, after all.  I feel like I'm missing something here, please help me out.

Thirdly, why can't C++ `std::string` be used as a buffer? Every time, they have to be converted to C strings.

Comment: `char` is special.

Comment: What is `sizeof(char)`?  Now, what is `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: 1 and 4. Now it makes sense why int[ ] is not used. But I just wanna know is it possible to do with int[ ], is there any limitations on using that, expect for the fact that it would use 4 times the space???

Comment: @Bad_Panda - You're actually missing the point.  The value of `sizeof(int)` is implementation-defined  i.e.  it can (and does!) vary between compilers.   `sizeof(char)` is `1` is fixed, since it is defined by the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why not just write the content in a string, and then when we receive it put in the string.

Because Boost ASIO is a library for binary IO; not for textual IO. And `std::string` is for representing text. Technically, you *could* use a `std::string` as a buffer for binary data, but doing so would be unconventional and confusing.

> why not int[]

Because the narrow character types are special in the C++ language.

Generally objects of one type cannot be observed as objects of another type. For example, if you have a `short` object and a `long long` object and want to send those over the network, you cannot "observe" at those objects as being (arrays) of `int` objects, because they aren't `int` obects. But, every object can be "observed" (through reinterpretation) as arrays of narrow character objects. That is the unique feature of `char`, `unsigned char` and `std::byte` which is why they are used as buffers for serialisation. And also that their size is exactly one byte which the fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model.

> which can store ASCII value

Which is largely irrelevant in binary IO since ASCII is a text encoding. It would also be quite wasteful to use 16 bits (at minimum; 32 bits on most systems) to represent ASCII that is a 7 bit encoding.

Comment: Hmm..this makes so much more sense to me. So what you are tryna say is that when we use **short** or **long long** it is some kind of formatting, I mean like after all they are too bunch of bytes but they are encoded in some way, which when sent it would not make sense until the receiver receives it in the same way, in the same format. This is the exact reason why we have serializing to send them in the common format. But then ASIO is a binary I/O so there is no serializing of no sort. The binary is just sent. This brings me back to the question how is char converted to binary? UTF-8 ?

Comment: "Their size is exactly one byte which is the smallest addressable unit of memory" is wrong in one way and misleading in one more.  It is a unit of memory which is small, addressable, and at least 8 bits, but that might not be the "smallest addressable unit" on any given platform.  And although this "addressable unit of at least 8 bits" is what the C++ standard calls "byte", it does not necessarily agree with the meaning the word "byte" has in the rest of the computing world.

Comment: @Bad_Panda `But then ASIO is a binary I/O so there is no serializing of no sort.`  Since you can only send a stream of bytes, and generally it is useful to send more higher level structures such as "integers" or "strings" or "classes", you must first perform serialisation i.e. "flatten" those structures into streams of bytes that can be "inflated" back on the other end. The ASIO library indeed doesn't do that for you.

Comment: @Bad_Panda `how is char converted to binary?`  No conversion is necessarily needed. You are sending an array of bytes (chars). You have a char. That is an array of chars of length one. It can be sent as it is. If the char represents text, then the source and the destination must agree upon what text encoding is used. If source uses encoding A, then the destination must know that it is A, and if destination wants to use it in another enconding, then it must convert from the A encoding that it receives. UTF-8 is quite commonly used in network communication.

Comment: Thanks @eerorika! A last one, let's say I'm sending only a bunch of characters, which in a way is a string, can I just encode it into utf-8 and send it?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, that is how "byte" is generally defined. I changed words to match the C++ standard. It's true that the language doesn't say "smallest". In practice though, have you encountered a C++ implementation on a system can address a unit smaller than `char`? I'd like to learn of an example.

Comment: @Bad_Panda If the receiver is expecting to receive a UTF-8 string, then sure. If they expect something else like a HTTP request for example, then no; it's not as simple in that case.

Comment: @Bad_Panda A `char` is not a character - it is something wider. What is stored in a `char` and how it's contents are interpreted, depends on the programmer.

Comment: I think this too misses the point. "why not just write the content in a string, and then when we receive it put in the string." - the premise is flawed: you *CAN* easily do exactly that. In fact [you can do everything you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584862/85371) which is the point.

Answer (score 3):

I think both the answers, by giving arguments against `string` or `int[]` miss the general point:

> Boost Doesn't Make That Choice For You

In other words

> You Are Free To Use All Of These To Your Taste

Demo **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ca90677fa1e0834)**:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Buffer>
size_t test_request(Buffer response) {
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

    boost::asio::io_context io;
    tcp::socket s(io);
    s.connect({ boost::asio::ip::address_v4{{1,1,1,1}}, 80 }); 

    write(s, boost::asio::buffer("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
         "Host: 1.1.1.1\r\n"
         "Referer: stoackoverflow.com\r\n"
         "\r\n"));

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    auto bytes = read(s, response, ec);
    std::cerr << "test_request: " << ec.message() << " at " << bytes << " bytes\n";

    return bytes;
}

#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::vector<char> vec(4096);
    int ints[1024];

    {
        auto n = test_request(boost::asio::buffer(vec));
        vec.resize(n);
    }

    // or use the ints[]
    test_request(boost::asio::buffer(ints));

    // use a dynamic buffer (that grows):
    test_request(boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(s));

    auto report = [](std::string_view sv) {
        std::cout << sv.length() << " bytes\n"
            << " first: " << std::quoted(sv.substr(0, sv.find_first_of("\r\n"))) << "\n"
            << " last:  " << std::quoted(sv.substr(sv.find_last_of("\r\n", sv.size()-3)+1)) << "\n";
    };

    std::cout << "String response: "; report(s);
    std::cout << "Vector response: "; report({vec.data(), vec.size()});
}
```

Prints

```
test_request: End of file at 909 bytes
test_request: End of file at 909 bytes
test_request: End of file at 909 bytes
String response: 909 bytes
 first: "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"
 last:  "</html>
"
Vector response: 909 bytes
 first: "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"
 last:  "</html>
"
```

### Summary

The whole point is not opinionism on text encodings or whatnot¹.

The whole point is

- Don't Pay For What You Don't Use (extra conversions take allocations and just cost performance)
- Non-Intrusive Framework (the framework should not dictate what *vocabulary types* you must use)

---

¹ (std::string is suitable for, say UTF8 or ASCII7 or indeed binary data - it will handle NUL chars just fine).

Comment: Hurrah!  `char*` is extremely compatible because (a) it is a raw pointer, as a non-owning pointer should be.  In a world of multiple smart pointer classes (`std::string`, `std::vector<char>`, `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, `std::shared_ptr<char[]>`) as well as automatic (e.g. local) variables and static data you don't want the API to force a particular smart pointer on you.  And (b) `char` can alias any data type.  Non-owning and universal.  The only real competition comes from `void*`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yup. And buffer abstractions (much like std::span or string_view etc) raise the level, which is why `boost::asio::buffer` is preferable over `char*`

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is the fact that the content of a buffer might not actually represent a string, it's just a block of memory that could represent anything. That should also explain why `std::string` shouldn't be used as a buffer.

The reason why char is used as a type is that it (usually) has a size of one byte, so the buffer is actually just an array of bytes, and having char as the type allows easy per-byte manipulation of that memory (like, for example, copying a block of memory at a specific byte offset into/out of the buffer, etc).

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is *defined* by the C++ standard as being `1`.

Comment: @Peter I suppose that it is *usual* for C++ implementations to adhere to the standard :)

Comment: @Peter: Indeed.  But the C++ standard does not require than one "C++ byte" (the units for `sizeof`) is the same as one computing byte (8-bits aka octet, what the entire rest of the world thinks the word *byte* means).  For example on TI's Cx2000 line of digital signal processors, `CHAR_BIT == 16`, `sizeof (char) == sizeof (short)`, `sizeof (long) == 2`, and `uint8_t` does not exist.

Comment: But isn't string too array of chars? But my main doubt is how are the bytes stored in the chars? If assume we are sending a bunch of letters or a string, with UTF8-encoding we can turn them into corresponding bits. But let's say we are sending a file, the encoding there will be different how will the receiver know what the sender is sending or is this something receiver should know?

Comment: @Bad_Panda Before data can be exchanged, the two ends must somehow agree on the format in which the data will be exchanged by some mechanism. There is no universal way to indicate entirely in a stream of bytes of data what its type or format is.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point. `std::string` is probably very capable, and it can in fact be used exactly like any other buffer can with ASIO. I explain in my answer